# RBG color variations from Publisher to Powerpoint

Tags: pdf, microsoft-powerpoint, colors, microsoft-publisher

I created some graphics in publisher to use in a powerpoint presentation, however, when I place the graphics into powerpoint the colors (same RBG color as used in publisher) don't match.  It becomes even more obvious when converting the powerpoint to a pdf.

Does anyone know where I can input true RBG colors and receive powerpoint rbg colors?

Thanks!

Comment: If Publisher is doing any color management, it's going to change RGB colors it displays in an attempt to get them to match what they'll look like on a (probably) CMYK output device or printing press.  PowerPoint does no color management. It simply displays the RGB colors as given.  Hard to say what's happening when you convert to PDF; there are probably a dozen different programs for that, and some of them have dozens of settings, any of which might affect the way it renders RGB colors from PPT into PDF.  More info might help.